# JAVA - Ignore part of strings containing "#"

Tags: java, string

I'm having some difficulties in excluding part of strings after the "#" symbol.

I explain myself better:

This is a sample input text a user could insert in a textbox:

```
Some Text
Some Text again #A comment
#A comment line
Another Text
Another Text again#Comment
```

I need to read this text and ignore all text after "#" symbol.

This should be the expected output:

```
Some Text;Some Text again;Another Text;Another Text again
```

As for now here's the code:

This replaces all newlines with ";"

```
readText = userInputTextArea.getText();
readTextAllInALine = readText.replaceAll("\\n", ";");
```

so the output after this is:

```
Some Text;Some Text again #A comment;#A comment line;Another Text;Another Text again#Comment
```

This code is to ignore all characters after the first "#" but works fine just for the first line if we read it all sequentially.

```
int startIndex = inputCommandText.indexOf("#");
int endIndex = inputCommandText.indexOf(";");
String toBeReplaced = inputCommandText.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
readTextAllInALine.replace(toBeReplaced, "");
```

I'm stuck in finding a way for having the expected output. I was thinking of using a StringTokenizer, processing every line, removing text after "#" or ignoring the whole line if it starts with "#", and then printing all tokens (i.e. all lines) separating them with ";" but I cannot make it work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you very much in advance.

Regards.

Comment: Please indicate your programming language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call this replace command on your pure string, retrieved from the text input. The regex **#[^;]*** grabs everything, starting at the hash until it reads a semicolon. Afterwards it replaces it with an empty string.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = "Some Text;Some Text again #A comment;#A comment line;Another Text;Another Text again#Comment";
    System.out.println(text);
    text = text.replaceAll("#[^;]*", "");
    System.out.println(text);
}
```

Comment: The OP's comments are end line comments so it doesn't work quite right. For example `Text #comment;Text;` will turn in to `Text Text;` when it should ideally be `Text;Text;`.

Comment: There are no line breaks inside the string since he already replaces them with semicolons

Comment: It works correctly!!Thank you very much for your help!!

As reported in previous comment `Text #comment;Text;` outputs as expected `Text;Text`

Comment: Yet the output isn't what's in the OP so it's not correct. `Some Text;Some Text again ;;Another Text;Another Text again`

Comment: Yep you are right, but I can simply ignore the `;;` situation since by being null the text contained between the two `;` symbols this works ok for my purpouses. Main issue was ignoring `#` lines.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A regex is useful here but it's tricky because your pattern is moderately complex. The comments are end line so they can appear in more than one arrangement.

I came up with the following which is a two-pass:

```
replaceAll(" *(#.*(?=\\n|$))", "").replaceAll("\\n+", ";");
```

The two-pass circumvents the fact that sometimes you get a duplicate line break. The first expression replaces comments but not new line characters and the second expression replaces multiple new line characters with a single semicolon.

The individual parts of the expression in the first pass are the following:

- `" *"`

This includes zero or more leading spaces in the comment match. IE in `"...again #A..."`, we want to remove that space between `n` and `#`.

- `"(#.* )"`

The start of the comment match: matches a `#` followed by zero or more characters. (Typically the `.` matches any character except a new line.)

- `"(?= )`"

This is a positive lookahead and where the regex starts to get tricky. It looks for whatever is inside this expression but doesn't include it in the text that's matched. It asserts that the `#.*` is followed by a certain string but doesn't replace that certain string.

- `"\\n|$"`

The lookahead finds a new line *or* the end anchor. This will find a comment ended with a new line character *or* a comment that is at the end of the String. But again, since it's inside the lookahead, the new line doesn't get replaced.

So given the input:

```
String text = (
    "Some Text" + '\n' +
    "Some Text again #A comment" + '\n' +
    "#A comment line" + '\n' +
    "Another Text" + '\n' +
    "Another Text again#Comment"
);

System.out.println(
    text.replaceAll(" *(#.*(?=\\n|$))", "").replaceAll("\\n+", ";")
);
```

The output is:

```
Some Text;Some Text again;Another Text;Another Text again
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to make it clear, Coxer's reply is the way to go. Far more precise and clean. But in any case, if you fancy experimenting here is a recursive solution that will work:

```
public class IgnoreHash {
@Test
public void test() {
    String readTextAllInALine = "Some Text;Some Text again #A comment;#A comment line;Another Text;Another Text again#Comment;";
    String actualResult = removeHashComments(readTextAllInALine);
    Assert.assertEquals(actualResult, "Some Text;Some Text again ;Another Text;Another Text again");

}

private String removeHashComments(String input) {
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    int hashIndex = input.indexOf("#");
    int endIndex = input.indexOf(";");

    if(hashIndex != -1){
        result.append(input.substring(0, hashIndex));
        //first line
        if(hashIndex < endIndex ) {
            result.append(removeHashComments(input.substring(endIndex)));
        } // the case of ;#
        else if (endIndex == hashIndex-1) {
            int endIndex2 = input.indexOf(";", hashIndex+1);
            result.append(removeHashComments(input.substring(endIndex2+1)));
        } 
        else {
            result.append(removeHashComments(input.substring(hashIndex)));
        }
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

}

Comment: Just curious, why would you assert equals against a result that's wrong? The OP stated their expected output.

Comment: You are right - I changed the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Well I guess the OP has retroactively said it doesn't matter so I'm not campaigning anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```
readText = userInputTextArea.getText();
readText = readText.replaceAll("\\s*#[^\n]*", "");
readText = readText.replaceAll("\n+", ";");
```